# Update Duplicate Records, Keeping the Record with Min(Date) the same

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

Here's my issue;

I run this query and get 13,469 users that have multiple rows where 'FirstTimeBooking' = 1:

```
Select CustUserId, COUNT(CustUserId)
FROM Bookings with (nolock)
WHERE FirstTimeBooking = 1
GROUP BY CustUserId
HAVING COUNT(CustUserId) > 1
ORDER BY COUNT(CustUserId) DESC
```

I need to update all of these records, setting FirstTimeBooking = 0 for each Row EXCEPT the Min(BookingDate) for each user(which is the actual FirstTimeBooking). Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: One change to the requirement; I need to update all of the records, setting FirstTimeBooking = 0 for each row EXCEPT Min(BookingDate) for each user, PER STORE that they are in.

I.e .   (A User can have a FirstTimeBooking in multiple stores, but not multiple FirstTimeBookings per store)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i tried to keep it simple and to stay with your syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE Bookings 
(
 CustUserID int
,FirstTimeBooking int
,BookingDate datetime
)

INSERT INTO Bookings VALUES 
 (1, 1, '20170101') 
,(1, 1, '20170101') -- Duplicate on same date
,(2, 1, '20170201')
,(2, 1, '20170301') -- On a second date
,(3, 1, '20170401')

UPDATE a
SET FirstTimeBooking = 0
FROM Bookings as a
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    -- Only CustUserID 1 and 2
    SELECT CustUserID, min(BookingDate) as BookingDate
    FROM Bookings
    WHERE FirstTimeBooking = 1
    GROUP BY CustUserID
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) as b
on a.CustUserID = b.CustUserID
and a.BookingDate = b.BookingDate
WHERE b.BookingDate IS NULL -- only where the first booking date has not been found in subquery

-- Still got the Problem with CustUserID
SELECT * 
FROM Bookings
WHERE CustUserID = 1

UPDATE b
set FirstTimeBooking = 0
FROM (
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustUserID ORDER BY CustUserID) As Rown
FROM Bookings as b
WHERE FirstTimeBooking = 1
) as b
WHERE Rown = 2

-- This is now also solved
SELECT * 
FROM Bookings
WHERE CustUserID = 1
```

Maybe you don't have two identical BookingDates, but I added this just in case.

Regards
tgr

Comment: if you want to perform this per store, just add the store to the groupings B-)